# Grails UrlMappings for a telephone number

Tags: model-view-controller, grails, groovy

I'd like to set it so when a user visits the application with a telephone number in the URL Grails directs the user to the specified profile, for example:

`localhost:8080/Application/profile/07871216969 -> /user/show/User.findByUserTelephone(07871216969)`

or preferably

`localhost:8080/Application/07871216969 -> /user/show/User.findByUserTelephone(07871216969)`

However, I have no idea how to reference the telephone number in the URL when calling the findByUserTelephone closure; I've noticed something like:

`/profile/$telephoneNumber` however I'm not entirely sure how that works out.

Also, as the /user/show action requires an id in the parameters I am not sure if the findUserByTelephone closure is any use as it returns the User as an object, and I can't seem to either getId() or .id the object to retrieve the id.

**SOLVED/SOLUTION:**

I solved this by creating another action in the Controller called `profile`, this action then had code similar to the following:

```
def profile = {
    if(User.findByUserTelephone(params.userTelephone)) {
        def userInstance = User.findByUserTelephone(params.userTelephone)

        if (!userInstance) {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), params.id])}"
            redirect(action: "list")
        }
        else {
            [userInstance: userInstance]
        }
    } else {
        render("Sorry, that user wasn't found in our database.")
    }
}
```

I then created the following UrlMapping entry:

```
`"/$userTelephone"(controller: "user", action: "profile")`
```

Thus, when a user enters a telephone number into the system (or any string after the `/`) it will route the user to the user/profile action, which will attempt to find a user by their telephone number. If successful, will show the users details otherwise will show an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably save you some headaches later if you use a url path which is not the same as a controller name.  So if you have something like:

```
"/p/$phoneNumber"(controller:profile, action:show)
```

you won't have any URL patterns that match multiple URLMapping entries which can get a little confusing.  I would guess that just:

```
"/$phoneNumber"(controller:profile, action:show)
```

would work, but I would expect to end up in situations where Grails gets confused by multiple URLMappings matching the same request path unless you're very careful.

Comment: Yeah, I ran into issues not long after coding the UrlMapping above and done something similar. Thanks. :-)